# Adding "snow" to a image

Tags: java, user-interface

Need to figure out how to add falling snow to the top of the picture and falls to the bottom and removes itself when it hits the bottom. Not sure what to do for it. I've tried putting in multiple versions of snow but they didn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;      
import java.awt.*;
public class SnowMan  extends JApplet

{

public void paint (Graphics frame)
{  
    final int MID = 150;    // middle of the snowman
    final int TOP = 50;     // top of the snowman
    frame.setColor (Color.cyan);
    frame.fillRect(0,0,300,250);
    frame.setColor (Color.blue);
    frame.fillRect (1, 175, 300, 50) ; 
    frame.setColor (Color.white);
    frame.fillOval (MID - 20, TOP, 40, 40);
    frame.fillOval (MID - 35, TOP + 35, 70, 50);
    frame.fillOval (MID - 50, TOP + 80, 100, 60);
    frame.setColor (Color.black); 
    frame.fillOval (MID - 10, TOP + 10, 5, 5);
    frame.fillOval (MID + 5, TOP + 10, 5, 5);
    frame.drawArc (MID - 10, TOP + 20, 20, 10, 190, 160);
    frame.drawLine (MID - 25, TOP + 60, MID - 50, TOP + 40);
    frame.drawLine (MID + 25, TOP + 60, MID + 55, TOP + 60);
    frame.drawLine (MID - 20, TOP + 5, MID + 20, TOP + 5);
    frame.fillRect (MID - 15, TOP - 20, 30, 25);
}
```

}

Comment: Explain what you mean by did not work

Comment: Snow didn't fall from the top and disappear on the bottom.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Where are you stuck? Creating the snowflakes? Drawing them? Animating them? Show what you tried.

Comment: Having trouble animating them where they appear at the top and fall to the bottom and disappear.

Comment: Suggestion: 1. draw the bg with the snowman 2. increment each snowflakes y-pos 3. check each snowflakes y-pos - if offscreen, remove from array 4. draw each snowflake 5. goto 1.

Comment: You've got no animation code whatsoever. Where's your Swing Timer? Suggestion: use a Swing Timer to drive animation, draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel that his held by the JApplet.